# What is wrong in my attempt to generate a random number by Box-Muller?

Tags: random, kdb

I am trying to generate a random number from the gaussian distribution using the Box-Muller method. However, my results are far from the truth.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
.stat.GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller:{ 
sq:{
    a:2.0*rand[abs[system"S"]]%abs[system"S"]-1;
    b:2.0*rand[abs[system"S"]]%abs[system"S"]-1;
    sq:(a*a)+(b*b);
    x:sq
   }/[{x>=1};1]; 

  :(2.0*rand[abs[system"S"]]%abs[system"S"]-1)*sqrt[(neg[2]*log[sq])%sq]
 };
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues in your answer: priority of operations in `q`, how to generate a random variable in [-1;1], and the condition on the variable `sq`.

**Priority of operations:**

Remind that below, `a1` and `a2` are different:

```
u:rand[1f];
a1:-1+2.0*u;
a2:2.0*u-1;

u:0.5
a1:0f
a2:-1f

u:0
a1:-1f
a2:-2f
```

**Generate a random variable in [-1;1]:**

Use the following:

```
a:-1+2.0*rand[1.0];
b:-1+2.0*rand[1.0];
```

**Condition on `sq`:**

You indeed took into account the `sq >= 1` condition, but you also have an issue if `sq = 0` as you have to divide by `sq` in the last step.

Besides, in your implementation you compute `a` twice, which 1) is not optimal and 2) is not consistent with the methodology as the same `a` has to be used in the computation of `sq` in the last step, the latter yielding to very large numbers. I got some inspiration from the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) where they suggest to regenerate `sq` should the above condition are not met. Hence a recursive call in the function in the implementation below:

```
.stat.GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller:{ 
    a:-1+2.0*rand[1.0];
    b:-1+2.0*rand[1.0];
    sq:(a*a)+(b*b);
    if[(sq>=1)|(sq=0);
        :.stat.GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller[];
    ];
    :a*sqrt[(neg[2]*log[sq])%sq];
 };
```

You can now have a look at the data generated by plotting the histogram of the following dataset:

```
([]val:{:.stat.GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller[]} each til 100000)
```

**EDIT:**

You could actually have a more efficient implementation by generating 2 random numbers per function call as follow:

```
.stat.GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller:{ 
    a:-1+2.0*rand[1.0];
    b:-1+2.0*rand[1.0];
    sq:(a*a)+(b*b);
    if[(sq>=1)|(sq=0);
        :.stat.GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller[];
    ];
    :(a*sqrt[(neg[2]*log[sq])%sq];b*sqrt[(neg[2]*log[sq])%sq]);
 };

([]val:raze {.stat.GetOneGaussianByBoxMuller[]} each til 50000)
```

This implementation takes 150 ms to generate 100000 normally-distributed random numbers while the one above takes 245 ms.